# Different behavior of ViewPager if i use AsyncTask or IntentService

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

My application, using ViewPager contains four Fragments, have different behavior if I use AsyncTask or an IntentService for retrieve data from a server. 
Initially i've implemented all by using AsyncTask, and perform a one time only download of data. Now i've mantained the same code (for building views, and initialize variables) but I've added a call of IntentService for download data continuously.
The problem is that if i use IntentService, the onCreateView of Fragments it's not called, and I can't call functions of Fragment Classess (the onCreateView retrieve also widget to modify inside Fragment).
This is the code of my main activity by using AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    // drop all
    database.clearAll();
    // download data
    downloadData();

    // build blocks
    pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm);
    // set properties
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setPageMargin(0);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    // retrieve Fragment object
    tableFragment = (TableFragment) adapter.getTableFragment();
    tempFragment = (TempFragment) adapter.getTempFragment();
    humFragment = (HumFragment) adapter.getHumFragment();
    mixFragment = (MixFragment) adapter.getMixFragment();

    // listener for show action bar
    pager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            int event = arg1.getAction();
            if (event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                showActionBar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    stored_data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
}

public void downloadData() {
    DownloadDataTask async_task = new DownloadDataTask(this, database);
    async_task.execute(null, null, null);
}

public void saveDataToList(ArrayList<String[]> list) {
    stored_data = list;
    // refresh fragments
    tableFragment.refresh(list);
    tempFragment.refresh(list);
    humFragment.refresh(list);
    mixFragment.refresh(list);
}
```

`saveDataToList()` it's called by AsyncTask after retrieve data from database and parse it into ArrayList.

ant this is one of Fragment implementation (the others are pretty same)

```
public class TableFragment extends Fragment {
    MainActivity main;
    ListView list_view;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
        list_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    /*
     * refresh current view with data retrieved from database
     */
    public void refresh(ArrayList<String[]> lista) {
        adapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        adapter.add("T: " + lista.get(i)[0] + " H: " + lista.get(i)[1]
            + " D: " + lista.get(i)[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code of mainActivity that start an `IntentService` is the same, without call `downloadData()` method, but with start of intentService at the beginning of `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadIntent.class);
    startService(intent);
    //same code
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    while (true) {
        Cursor data = database.getData();
        if (data.getCount() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] to_add;

            if (data.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!data.isAfterLast()) {
                    to_add = new String[3];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        to_add[i] = data.getString(i);
                    }

                    data.moveToNext();
                    list.add(to_add);
                }
            }
            data.close();
            saveDataToList(list);
        }

        try {
            Log.i("AAAAAAA!", "main sleep");
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'onCreateView of Fragments it's not called, and I can't call functions of Fragment Classess'? Why do you 'can't' call fragment functions? How and then do you add fragments to layout?

Comment: i've put some Log.i on my code and if i use AsyncTask, onCreateView it's called after asyncTask execute doInBackground. If i use Service, onCreateView is not executed. for fragments i've use the "standard" code of FragmentAdapter class used in ViewPager layout tutorials

Comment: Call of AsyncTask execute and onCreateView are not related at all (unless You're not providing complete code). Also, in android there's no FragmentAdapter class at all. Haven't you observed any exception in logcat using service btw?

Comment: It's not a standard class. It's a Class used for manage ViewPager layout. This is an example code:
http://just-another-blog.net/programming/how-to-implement-horizontal-view-swiping-with-tabs/

Comment: Seems You want to say 'FragmentPagerAdapter' instead of 'FragmentAdapter'. Could You explain why have you provided 'onResume()' in the second example? Have You tried to remove while(true) from there, so execution of activity code would be able to continue?